# Does Neo4j backup/restore mean Export/Import of graph database?

Tags: neo4j, export, database-backups

I am new to graph database technique (switching from relational db).

In [neo4j](/questions/tagged/neo4j) there is option of [backup strategy and restoring of graph database](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/operations-backup.html). While doing development my team should be able to have same graph db.

Is it same concept as export/import of relational databases?
Does webadmin of [neo4j](/questions/tagged/neo4j) option of export/import like of [phpmyadmin](/questions/tagged/phpmyadmin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Neo4j` backup basically creates a consistent full copy of the binary representation of your graph. You can move the directory created with neo4j-backup directly to `data/graph.db` directory of your server and start Neo4j. So the `import` step gets reduced to simply copying stuff over.

Comment: Does backup mean export? Is there any option to do it from webadmin in browser?

Comment: backup is done by either a shell script `neo4j-backup` or via Java API, see docs for this. PLease not that online backup is a feature of the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

In graph databases, data is stored as key=>pair. So there is no any schema stored in engine.

In neo4j data is stored on data folder. In [neo4j](/questions/tagged/neo4j), [backup and restoring of graph database](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/operations-backup.html) is same as export/import in relational database like [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql).

Currently there is no option to backup/restore from webadmin. We can do it from console.

Answer (score 1):

I use $NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-shell -c dump > myDump.cypher

Then from web Console you can import the file and run it.
Or even with the same tool you can import:

./bin/neo4j-shell -v -file myDump.cypher

Comment: Also would be reasonable to add, that importing standard dump.cypher may cause issues for huge dumps. To resolve them you can split transactions to separate instructions with script like this: 
https://gist.github.com/garmoshka-mo/f27c1884bc1851ebf7b23bf4137095f9